# How to force set in c++ to store values in descending order?

Tags: c++, set

I have been stuck on an algorithm that requires unique values sorted in descending order. Since the need is unique, I thought set is the best data structure to be used here, but I guess set by default stores the value in non-decreasing order, how do I make it store in non-increasing order?

Other than the fact that I can let it store in ascending order and then reverse the set, is there any other modification that I can do?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "algorithm"; if it's an algorithm in the sense that the C++ standard library provides, it takes its input through a pair of iterators, and all you need to do is pass `my_set.rbegin()` and `my_set.rend()` to the algorithm. Those produce reverse iterators, so the algorithm will go backwards through the set.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about using `std::set<int, std::greater<int>> mySet{}`? By default it's using `std::less` if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the set can be changed by changing/defining operator < for the objects stored in your set.